# How to add css file in Laravel 5.6 with npm

Tags: css, laravel, npm

**This is my step**

1. npm install bootstrap-select
2. edit resource/assets/bootstrap.js and add "require('bootstrap-select');"
3. npm run prod

**My Questions:**

but lib bootstrap-select include sass or css files, how do I combine sass or css files in css/app.css ?

Is it only way that edit webpack.mix.js? or I can edit some file like "resource/assets/bootstrap.js"

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to include the bootstrap-select sass files within your own sass.

Something like that in your `resources/assets/sass/app.scss`:

```
...
@import '~bootstrap-select/sass/bootstrap-select';
....
```

That way you can use their variables within your own sass files. And it will automatically be compiled into your `public/css/app.css`.

Or if you don't want to use the variables, you could just import the css from your sass file and still have it compile into app.css:

```
@import '~bootstrap-select/dist/css/bootstrap-select';
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer it.